# PLACEHOLDER - answer_cleanup

Tags: app, placeholder

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Insert a reasonably sized screenshot (or code snippet) of your
app here, so we can get a quick look at it and
an idea of how it works and what it might do for us.

### About

Tell us about your app.
Why did you create it? Who is it for?
How does it work? What problem does it solve?

#### License

What license is your app released under, if any?
Or if it is paid, how much does it cost and how do we buy it?

#### Download

Provide links for us to obtain your app.
For websites or service, provide link to the main or home page.
A user should be able to jump to this section and dive right into your app.

#### Platform

What platform or browser is your app for?
Android? PC? Mac? Apple Newton? Firefox? Opera? Lynx?

### Contact

Who created this app? Who are the key contributors?
How do we get in touch with them or find them?

### Code

What language, frameworks, and tools were used to write this?
Where can we get the code?
How can we contribute to the code?